# Zend Framework 2: Clear some meta param from headMeta() view Helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I set several default meta parametres in the Module.php:

```
$hm =  $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('headMeta');
$hm
  ->appendProperty('og:image', '/images/opengraph/1.jpg')
  ->appendProperty('og:image', '/images/opengraph/2.png');
```

Later one in some action I need to override these meta params and set some other images. I have no idea how to clear these existing 'og:image' params...  I've tried:

```
$hm->appendProperty('og:image', null);
//and
$hm->unsetProperty('og:image');
```

But none worked. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the append method doesn't add a og:image's over the one already defined. The append method will append the next og:image to the og:image already defined, you end up with an array of them. Similarly, if you chose prepend, this would add your new og:image tag before the ones you already defined in.

I think what you really want is to set the property initially, rather than apending it.

```
$hm =  $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('headMeta');
$hm->setProperty('og:image', '/images/opengraph/1.jpg');
```

then later:

```
$hm->setProperty('og:image', '/images/opengraph/2.jpg');
```

or even later:

```
$hm->setProperty('og:image', '/images/opengraph/2.jpg');
```

If you absolutely want to blow away the list, as a last resort you can see this link: [Zend Framework: Clearing/Resetting HeadLink, HeadMeta, HeadScript, HeadStyle and HeadTitle](http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/zend-framework-clearing-resetting-headlink-headmeta-headscript-headstyle-and-headtitle/) based on ZF1 but looking at the ZF2 code appears to be the same.

Perhaps a better solution to the overall challenge is not eagerly set the og:image's in the module, but to always set them as late as possible so you are not in this situation.

Comment: ight - but I do in fact need multiple og:image... so - even if I call set initially - how do I remove it later? I don't get how one in general removes something from headMeta placeholder?

Comment: I see. There is no way to merely clear the list of multiple entries as you want to do. I'll update the answer with a couple of links that will demonstrate how you can completely blow away your headMeta and rebuild it from scratch tho.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't answer your question. It has to do with how headMeta internally stores the properties ... if you append, it becomes an array ... if you set, it is just a parameter.

Comment: ahh yes  - I've got to that one too. But calling $this->headX()->exchangeArray(array()) would actually clean entire headMeta - and there are 10 times more things in there.. So that's kinda.. won't work i guess.   and one can't even dump headmeta, change one thing and repopulate it...

Comment: "but to always set them as late as possible" I guess that's how it would have to work then. Tanks Bubba.